# Find System Error Code from Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I want to get System error code from the exception received.

e.g. If I pass some invalid path to following method, it throws an exception.

```
Directory.GetAccessControl(@"\\XYZServerPath\");
```

It throws an exception with inner exception null and Message as :

> Method failed with unexpected error code 161.

How do I get the System Error Code 161 from the exception? So that I can show a proper message instead of this exception's Message?

Preferably I do not want to parse this message in any way to get the number 161.

Comment: look at the HResult property of the exception

Comment: What do you plan to do with the system error code?

Comment: You can catch InvalidOperationException and dig out the error code with System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().  This is a strong implementation detail, you'll get away with it.

Comment: Steven, Which property in HResult would give me System Error Code? I get -2146233079 number from HResult.

Comment: Hans, I got '1008' instead od 161 from the code execution.

Comment: John, I want to show proper message to the user instead of some message like 'Method failed with unexpected error code 161.'

Comment: Can't you simply handle the exception by showing a message written by you, instead of the exception's message? That'd be a proper message.

Comment: Yes but according to the error code received I can change my message.